# Button inside my Datalist is not adding products

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm having problems with my DataList that is supossed to add a specific product:

I create a list (sorry for the spanish variables)

```
 List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
```

that I fill when user searches for it:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess bd = new DataAccess();
        product = bd.GetProduct(txtsearch.Text);
        UpdateBinding();
    }
```

(I have a class to access the database and get data about a product)

And next I update the Datalist with the items on the list

```
public void UpdateBinding()
    {
        DataProduct.DataSource = product;
        DataProduct.DataBind();
    }
```

**But when i want to add a product to the cart, it adds nothing, the button inside the Datalist template has the command name "addtocart"**

```
if (e.CommandName == "addtocart")
        {
            DataProduct.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            foreach (DataListItem item in DataProduct.Items)
            {
                string ID = ((HiddenField)item.FindControl("lbl_ID")).Value;
                string description = ((HiddenField)item.FindControl("lbl_descip")).Value;
                double price = double.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("lbl_price")).Value);
                AddItem(ID, description, price);
            }
            Response.Redirect("~/Cliente/cart.aspx");
        }
```

This is the button inside the `Itemtemplate`

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="addtocart" OnClick="btnagregar_Click"/>
```

I tried with `IsPostBack` on the pageload but nothing

```
if (IsPostBack)
 {
     UpdateBinding();
 }
```

Comment: sorry for some spanish names and/or variables, I hope it's not a problem

Comment: Probably too late but is your add to cart code inside of a method called btnagregar_Click or is it in the DataList's ItemCommand event?  Is the problem that your add to cart code never executes or that the AddItem method is being executed but doesn't work?